# How to show grand total amount in english words Magento 2 invoice pdf?

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, grand-total, amount

In Magento 2 invoice pdf, how can I show grand total amount in english words also? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Convert Using [NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(1432);
```

**Output :-**

```
one thousand four hundred thirty-two
```

Comment: where can i add it in the magento 2 invoice  pdf?

Comment: in which postion to disaply words ?

Comment: under the grand total

Comment: please attach screen shot